# Css first-child not working by dynamic slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use a dynamic slider, that adds the class "active" to the sliders that are active. There are always 4 sliders active.

I want to add custom css to the first active slider. It works perfect on load, but when changing the slider, it does not work anymore. Because the active class is added to next elements.

How can I solve this with css?

css:

```
.products-grid .active:first-child .item {border-left: 0px solid #e6e6e6;}
.products-grid .active .item {border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;}
```

html:

```
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 300px;">
    <li class="item effect-pageLeft">
        <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="product-action">
                inner HTML
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>

<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 300px;">
    <li class="item effect-pageLeft">
        <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="product-action">
                inner HTML
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>

<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 300px;">
    <li class="item effect-pageLeft">
        <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="product-action">
                inner HTML
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>

<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 300px;">
    <li class="item effect-pageLeft">
        <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="product-action">
                inner HTML
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>

<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 300px;">
    <li class="item effect-pageLeft">
        <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="product-action">
                inner HTML
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>

<div class="owl-item" style="width: 300px;">
    <li class="item effect-pageLeft">
        <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="product-action">
                inner HTML
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post your html or make a question snippet? ( also note that `:first-child` only applies to first childs, in your case you seem to be trying to select your first `.active` child, but that won't work unless is actually a `:first-child` )

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Added the HTML. I know that the `:first-child` only applies to the first child. But the first child is changing when switching the silder, because the `active` class is added to the next item and removed from the previous.

Comment: In your HTML there is not any `.active` element that is `:first-child`, so the selector won't work. you should read this https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Thanks, good to know! But how can I solve this issue, that only the first .active child, does not have the border?

Comment: you could use jquery `$('.active).eq(0).css('border-left', '0px solid #e6e6e6' ).siblings('border-left','0px solid red');` but you will have to update it for every change

Comment: Can you demonstrate the style in which you desire? Perhaps you could create an example on jsFiddle and share? Or a screen shot would help. I believe you may be able to achieve the style using a different method.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Thanks, looks like the code is not complety correct. Are you missing some phrases?

Comment: use jquery `$('.products-grid .active).css('border-left', '0px solid #e6e6e6' );  $('.products-grid .active).eq(0).css('border-left','0px solid red')`

Comment: @HenkZ you are right, it was just a demo though: `$('.active).eq(0).css('border-left', '0px solid #e6e6e6' ).siblings().css('border-left','0px solid red');`